# Collapse & expand div

Tags: jquery

I make a jquery collapse & expand div. its working but I face a problem that only [+] & span [-] is clickable but i want li means `<li>main link 1<span>[+]</span>` as clickable

```
  <ul class="link">
  <li>main link 1<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="link">
  <li>main link 2<span>[+]</span>

     <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="link">
<li>main link 3<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="link">
 <li>main link 4<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

script is:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript"                  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
 $('.link span').click(function () {
var $ul = $(this).next();
$(".inner_div").not( $ul ).hide();
$( '.link span' ).html( '[+]' );
if( !$ul.is( ':visible' ) ) {
    $( this ).html( '[&ndash;]');
}
$ul.slideToggle();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.link' ).first().click();
});
 </script>
```

css is:-

```
.inner_div{ display:none; }
.link span { float: right; cursor: pointer; }
```

please help me.

Comment: Here is a jsbin demo http://jsbin.com/inexar/1/edit

Comment: Can you rewrite as <span>main link 1[+]</span>? The other alternative is to assign the <li> a unique class and have your click on that class rather than '.link span'.

Comment: If I rewrite it as <span>main link 1[+]</span> then I lost the functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Code**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  <ul class="link">
  <li class="expan">main link 1<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="link">
  <li class="expan">main link 2<span>[+]</span>

     <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="link">
<li class="expan">main link 3<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="link">
 <li class="expan">main link 4<span>[+]</span>

    <ul class="inner_div">
        <li><a>test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.expan').click(function () {
  var $ul = $(this).find('span').next();
  $(".inner_div").not($ul).hide();
  $( '.expan span' ).html( '[+]' );
  if( !$ul.is( ':visible' ) ) {
    $(this).find('span').html( '[&ndash;]');
  }
  $ul.slideToggle();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expan').first().click();
});
```

**CSS Code**

```
.inner_div{ display:none; }
.link span { float: right; cursor: pointer; }
.expan { cursor: pointer;}
```

JS Bin link [here](http://jsbin.com/inexar/8/edit)

Comment: Thanks its working. But By default first ul is not shown. Please help me in this also

Comment: @AnkitaAgrawal : Edited my answer, please check JS Bin.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I only change $(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.expan' ).first().click();
});

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one: [**`checkout updated fiddle here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTUY9/3/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link ul').hide();
    $('.link li').click(function () {
       ($('span', this).text() == '[+]') ? $('span', this).html('[-]') : $('span', this).html('[+]');
       $('> ul', this).slideToggle();
       $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
       $(this).parent().siblings().find('span').html('[+]');
    });
    $('.link li').first().click();
});
```

and css should be:

```
 .link li{cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: tryout that in fiddle link above.

Comment: It's not working properly, when we expand one div, other div must get collapsed.

Comment: I Think yet it's causing problem. Expand one div and try to collapse the same.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't collapse div when i expand other div. Now My problem is solved. Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: @Jai Not yet, expand one div, than exapand other. You can find loophole in [+] and [-]. Previous divs sign is not getting changed to [+] while collapsing that is caused by other div.

Answer (score 0):

[Check Output Here](http://jsbin.com/inexar/5)

I have changed CSS slightly such that width of your `.link span` lies over the main link 1

```
.link span {position:absolute; width:80%; float: right; cursor: pointer; margin-left: -20%;}
```

Also align tag is used `<span align="right">[+]</span>` Since there is change in CSS

[Check Here](http://jsbin.com/inexar/5/edit)

Comment: Thanks its working. But By default first ul is not shown. Please help me in this also.